# Multiple Collection Views with same XIB Cell and button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a View Controller with multiple Collection Views.

Each collection view is using the same custom cell with xib.  In this xib i have a button.

The collectionViews names are

```
1) manPerfumeCV
2) womanPerfumeCV
3) kidsPerfumeCV
```

Inside `cellForItemAt` i have `cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row`

```
    let cell:iPhoneCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "iPhoneCell", for: indexPath) as! iPhoneCollectionViewCell
    if collectionView == self.womanPerfumeCV {

        let prods = womanPerfumeData[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(products: prods)
        cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row

    } else if collectionView == self.manPerfumeCV {
        let prods = manPerfumeData[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(products: prods)
        cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row

    } else if collectionView == self.kidsPerfumeCV {
        let prods = kidsPerfumeData[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(products: prods)
        cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row

    }
```

and in the same view controller i have this action for the button from the xib file

```
@IBAction func iPhoneAddToCart(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let butt = sender as! UIButton
        let indexP = IndexPath(row: butt.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = manPerfumeCV.cellForItem(at: indexP) as! iPhoneCollectionViewCell

        print(manPerfumeData[indexP.row].price)

    }
```

Each collection view has its own [Products] array.

```
1) manPerfumeData
2) womanPerfumeData
3) kidPerfumeData.
```

In my code if i tap at the button which is at the 1st collection view with manPerfumeData it prints the price very well.

Although if i push the button on the 2nd or 3rd collection view the app crashes.

Is there any way to know from wich collection view he pushed the button so i can load the spesific [Products] array ??

Thanks!

Comment: what do you see in debugger output?

Comment: @SinaKH fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-01-30 14:25:38.928171 Aromania[19538:6823926] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Its because in `print` i have only the `manPerfumeData`.
How can i recognise in which collection view was the button pressed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tag` property of `UIButton`.
Let consider your code

```
let cell:iPhoneCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "iPhoneCell", for: indexPath) as! iPhoneCollectionViewCell
if collectionView == self.womanPerfumeCV {
    //Your Code
    cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row + 1000

} else if collectionView == self.manPerfumeCV {
    //Your Code
    cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row + 2000

} else if collectionView == self.kidsPerfumeCV {
    //Your Code
    cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row + 3000
}
```

You noticed that I changed the `tag` property of `UIButton`. Now when tap on button, check `tag` property of `UIButton`. Like this

```
if (sender.tag >= 1000 && sender.tag<2000)
{
  //manPerfumeCV
}
else if (sender.tag >= 2000 && sender.tag<3000)
{
  //womanPerfumeCV
}
else
{
  //kidsPerfumeCV
}
```

For fetching value from array, subtract the beginning value from `tag` property and you will get value, like this

For **manPerfumeCV**

```
indexValue = sender.tag - 1000
```

For **womanPerfumeCV**

```
indexValue = sender.tag - 2000
```

For **kidsPerfumeCV**

```
indexValue = sender.tag - 3000
```

This value can directly use for getting data from array.

Comment: yes its correct!!! I figured out about the last update that you made that i have to make  `- 1000` or anyway the number that i added above at each tag ! thanks a lot mate :D

Answer (score 2):

inorder to achieve it you can add tag property to the collectionViews in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

// your code

self.womanPerfumeCV.tag = 0;
self.manPerfumeCV.tag = 1;
self.kidsPerfumeCV = 2;

}
```

using this you can identify the source

**// Now its time to listen to the buttonEvent**

I would suggest to keep the event listener in the same controller or make a protocol callback only with index and tag. 
 To keep it simple lets make the changes in same viewController File

```
if collectionView == self.womanPerfumeCV {

    let prods = womanPerfumeData[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(products: prods)
    cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row

} else if collectionView == self.manPerfumeCV {
    let prods = manPerfumeData[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(products: prods)
    cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row

} else if collectionView == self.kidsPerfumeCV {
    let prods = kidsPerfumeData[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(products: prods)
    cell.productCart.tag = indexPath.row

}

cell.yourButton.tag = (collectionView.tag * 1000 )+(indexPath.row);
        cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

**now add selector to event**

```
func ButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let index : Int = sender.tag % 1000;
    switch sender.tag {
      case let x where x < 1000:
      loadDataFromFirstArrayWithIndex(index);break;
      case let x where x <2000:
      loadDataFromSecondArrayWithIndex(index);break;
      default:
      loadDataFromThirdArrayWithIndex(index);

    } 
}
```